# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm currently learning React and I try to do a calendar with a login system but I have an issue with the login page. It returns me the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__H')" but I don't understand it. Is someone has a soluce ?

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.5",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^6.1.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datetime": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.16.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My Login page code :

```
import { useState,useRef } from "preact/hooks";
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import AddUserModal from "./AddUserModal";
import Calendar from "./Calendar"


function Login(){
    const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const userRef = useRef(null);

    const onUserAdded = user => {
        let userApi = userRef.current.getApi();
        userApi.addEvent({
            userId: user.usernameId,
            password:   user.password,
            email: user.email,
            holidayCount: user.holidayCount
        });
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <input placeholder="Utilisateur"></input>
                <input placeholder="Mot de passe"></input>
                <button >
                    <NavLink to={"/calendar"}>Connexion</NavLink>
                </button>
                <br/>
                <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)}>Add User</button>
            </form>

            <AddUserModal isOpen={modalOpen} onClose={() => setModalOpen(false)} onUserAdded={event => onUserAdded(event)} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Error :

[image]

I tried to install preact because i saw on internet some people have this issue with preact

I also tried this: https://github.com/shuding/nextra/issues/589#issuecomment-1194603089

Comment: Are you using Preact or React? Your provided code imports from `preact/hooks`, but Preact isn't a dependency in your application. It looks like you accidentally imported hooks from Preact when you should be importing from React.

Comment: I'm using react, I just checked my imports but I don't see any reference to preact

Comment: I also see "import { useState,useRef } from "preact/hooks";" this line in your Login page. useState and useRef must be imported form 'react'

Comment: Oh ! i didn't see it, the import was certainly made automatically. Thanks !